# make play and stop music with same button swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer

How to make music play and stop with single button just like in itunes.When the button is pressed and same button pressed again should stop the music.

```
  var audioplayer = AVaudioPlayer
 @IBAction func play(_ sender: Any) {

    do
    {

        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer (contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "bensound", ofType: "mp3")!))
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()
        audioPlayer.stop()

    }
    catch {
        print ("error")

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, this won't work:

```
audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
audioPlayer.play() // this will just start playing the music and immediately stop it.
audioPlayer.stop()
```

You need an if statement and a variable indicating whether the music is playing.

Luckily, the variable that I was talking about already exists! You don't even need to declare it yourself! It is [`isPlaying`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudioplayer/1390139-isplaying), defined in `AVAudioPlayer`.

We just need to write the if statement. It is pretty simple,

> If the music is playing, stop it, otherwise, start it

```
if audioplayer.isPlaying {
    audioplayer.play()
} else {
    audioplayer.stop()
}
```